# Tomcat 6.0.35 Windows 32b Service useSystemProxies

Tags: java, windows, windows-services, tomcat6, http-proxy

I've been trying the whole day to make Tomcat6 use system proxy settings. Tried various ways, about 200 different Versions of

```
tomcat6 //US/Tomcat6 ++JvmOptions "-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true"
```

I tried to set the property in `service.bat` in the "install" section like this (also many similar versions):

```
...
:foundJvm
echo Using JVM:              "%PR_JVM%"
"%EXECUTABLE%" //IS//%SERVICE_NAME% --StartClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StopClass org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap --StartParams start --StopParams stop --JvmOptions "-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true"
```

I tried settings this with the tomcat6w GUI. Not sure if it does anything anyway.

Also tried setting `JAVA_HOME` to JRE and JDK. No difference.

Tried setting `-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxyhostURL` and `-Dhttp.proxyPort=proxyPortNumber`. Those at least seem not to be ignored because the connection then failed (used random local ip and port).

Now the fun fact: I can run it through `catalina.bat`, set the parameter there (`CATALINA_OPTS=...`) and it works like a charm. So what is that doing there? I would like to have it as a service which would be way more user friendly, but if there's no way to achieve it, I'm willing to consider just throwing `catalina.bat` into autorun.

So... did anybody ever get that working? Or does anybody have ideas/advices?

Comment: Do you have authentication on your proxy? This is for outbound connections, right ?

Comment: @BGR Yes, it is for outbound connection. No authentication. I'm printing the found proxies. As a service it's always DIRECT. If I run it from the .bat it uses the system proxy properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming this is on Windows, I found a Registry key under:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Apache Software Foundation\Procrun 2.0\<app-name>\Parameters\Java
```

The entry is named `Options` of type `REG_MULTI_SZ`. This contained all the -D JVM options, one line per option. I added our HTTP/HTTPS proxy name (we're using NTLM authentication proxies)

```
-Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.company.local
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttps.proxyHost=proxy.company.local
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080
-Dhttp.proxyUser=svc_account
-Dhttp.proxyPassword=svc_Password
```

Comment: Great answer. Can't verify it works though, because I moved on to another company. I believe this might be the solution so I'll accept it. Thanks again!

Comment: This helped me find a solution - in my case, I run multiple Tomcat servers. Using the `tomcat6w.exe` in any one of them was updating the registry entries for the "Tomcat6" installation. The trick for me was to rename the `exe` files, then update the appropriate references in `service.cmd` before reinstalling the service.