# Export feature not working when I installed Sakai as windows service

Tags: windows, tomcat6, sakai

I am unable to resolve export issue in Sakai LMS when I installed as windows service.

This functionality is working fine, when i use startup.bat from command line as I have included "-dhttp.proxyhost" and "-dhttp.proxyport".

However, it's not working though I included above options in tomcat6w.exe (in java tab). Have also verified in Registry key and it's correctly appear.

Any help on this would be more helpful.

Here are the configurations details:

Sakai 2.9.1
Apache tomcat6
Windows server 2008 (64 bit)

Have received an error message "org.sakaiproject.tool.assessment.qti.helper.AuthoringHelper - Connection timed out: connect
java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect"

Thanks,
Sakthi. S

Answer (score 1):

This is not really related to Sakai but rather is related to tomcat6. You can find the answer here: [Tomcat 6.0.35 Windows 32b Service useSystemProxies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809107/tomcat-6-0-35-windows-32b-service-usesystemproxies)